# How to setup array with azure get command with powershell

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm a total Powershell newb and still learning.
I am trying to get a list of Azure Webjobs that has been stopped in a webapp. I understand when i run the command az webapp webjob continuous list, id get a large set of array data.

I am having troubles with splitting it up, could someone advise how would i split it up as individual jobs and their properties?
i tried $webjobs = ($webname.Split('}')) and it wont split up the giant array.

This is my current code

$groups = get-AzResourceGroup | where{$_.ResourceGroupName -like "*Dev*"}
foreach($group in $groups){

```
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "processing resourceGroup" $group.ResourceGroupName
$webApps = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $group.ResourceGroupName

foreach($webApp in $webApps){
    
   write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow $webApp.Name        
    
   $webname = (az webapp webjob continuous list --name $webApp.Name --resource-group $group.ResourceGroupName --query '[].name' -o tsv)
   $webstatus = (az webapp webjob continuous list --name $webApp.Name --resource-group $group.ResourceGroupName --query '[].status' -o tsv)
   
   Write-host $webname
   Write-host $webstatus
           
    }
    }
```

The result i get is...

processing resourceGroup dev
hub-dev-app-hub
hubv3-dev-app-hub/Data hubv3-dev-app-hub/ProcessToolData hubv3-dev-app-hub/ToolDataNotifications hubv3-dev-app-hub/UploadLasToSftp hubv3-dev-app-hub/ApplicationInsightsProfiler3 hubv3-dev-app-hub/DaaS
Running Running Running Running Running Stopped
hubv3-dev-app-authservice
hubv3-dev-app-authservice/ApplicationInsightsProfiler3
Running
hubv3-dev-app-api
hubv3-dev-app-api/ApplicationInsightsProfiler3
Running

What i am hoping to achieve is

hub-dev-app-hub
hubv3-dev-app-hub/Data Running
hubv3-dev-app-hub/ProcessToolData Running
hubv3-dev-app-hub/ToolDataNotifications Running
hubv3-dev-app-hub/UploadLasToSftp Running
hubv3-dev-app-hub/ApplicationInsightsProfiler3 Running
hubv3-dev-app-hub/DaaS Stopped

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you get is expected for the code written. Taking into account [tsv docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/format-output-azure-cli#tsv-output-format), means that `$webname` and `$webstatus` are arrays. When you write `Write-Host $webstatus` it will print all the data in the array, in this case:

```
Running
Running
Running
Running
Running
Stopped
```

What you could do is the following:

```
$webname = (az webapp webjob continuous list --name $webApp.Name --resource-group $group.ResourceGroupName --query '[].name' -o tsv)
$webstatus = (az webapp webjob continuous list --name $webApp.Name --resource-group $group.ResourceGroupName --query '[].status' -o tsv)

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $webname.length; $i++) {
    Write-Host $webname[$i]
    Write-Host $webstatus[$i]
}
```

But what you **should** do is use another query: `[].[name, status]`. Have a look at [jmesPath](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html).

This is better because you only do 1 request instead of two, and it should have the format that you would expect, i.e. array of name and status.

```
$webjobInfo = (az webapp webjob continuous list --name $webApp.Name --resource-group $group.ResourceGroupName --query '[].[name, status]' -o tsv)

Write-Host $webJobInfo
```

Comment: Dam, i was close, i tried $webjobInfo = (az webapp webjob continuous list --name $webApp.Name --resource-group $group.ResourceGroupName --query '[].name' '[].status' -o tsv).

Your answer made so much sense. I knew i had to add a count and repeat somewhere but couldnt picture where and how. thanks for your help

Comment: Np, if it helped you, consider accepting the answer.